# How to parse an XML using NSXMLParser with different Nodes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml-parsing

I know it may look like a duplicate for XML Parsing posts but i am really not able to understand the nodes and the delegate methods on how they behave. I have an XML..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ParticipantService>
    <Response>
        <CourseProperties>
            <CourseTitle>AICC_Flash_Workshop_PPT_to_web_examples</CourseTitle>
            <CourseCode>123456</CourseCode>
            <Availability>Open</Availability>
            <Status>In Progress</Status>
            <ImageLink>HTTP://lmsstaging.2xprime.com/images/inprogress_icon.png</ImageLink>
            <CategoryCode>0</CategoryCode>
            <CategoryDesc>General</CategoryDesc>
        </CourseProperties>
        <CourseProperties>
            <CourseTitle>Behaviours</CourseTitle>
            <CourseCode>OBIUS</CourseCode>
            <Availability>Open</Availability>
            <Status>In Progress</Status>
            <ImageLink>HTTP://lmsstaging.2xprime.com/images/inprogress_icon.png</ImageLink>
            <CategoryCode>0</CategoryCode>
            <CategoryDesc>General</CategoryDesc>
        </CourseProperties>
        <CourseProperties>
            <CourseTitle>Customer Service Skills (Part - one)</CourseTitle>
            <CourseCode>css_1</CourseCode>
            <Availability>Open</Availability>
            <Status>In Progress</Status>
            <ImageLink>HTTP://lmsstaging.2xprime.com/images/inprogress_icon.png</ImageLink>
            <CategoryCode>0</CategoryCode>
            <CategoryDesc>General</CategoryDesc>
        </CourseProperties>
```

....

My requirement is to store the relevant course details into respective array's. so i declared six nsmutablearray's but getting confused on how to retreive the data from the XMl.  I am trying it out this way

in foundCharacters method i am appending the value of string as

```
videoUrlLink = [NSMutableString stringWithString:string];
```

and in didEndElement method

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"CourseTitle"]) {
        [courseDetailList addObject:string];

    }
```

but at the end of the XMl i am able to store only one Value in the array. Please let me know if i am going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a class called `Course`, and a `Course` object has properties for `title`, `code`, `availability` and so on.

Make an iVar `currentCourse`.

Then, in your `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` (note: did **start**, not end!) method:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"CourseProperties"]) {
    //create a new course object
    currentCourse = [[Course alloc] init];
}
```

This gives context to all the properties of the course that follow. In the `didEndElement:` method, you basically do this for all the course properties:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"CourseTitle"]) {
    [currentCourse setTitle:string];
}
```

And, last but not least, once the `CourseProperties` closing tag is found, save the new course somewhere (also in `didEndElement:`):

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"CourseProperties"]) {
    //create a new course object
    [allMyCourses addObject:currentCourse];
    currentCourse = nil;
}
```

Comment: In this case how to retrieve the values from the stored data? I mean How to get all the course titles,availability, status e.t.c....???

Comment: U have mentioned to add string to currentCourse in didEndElement: method. But here in this element u will not be having the string attribute. Can u please check the same?